CreateWindowEx function returns NULL but last error is S_OK
Hello I just want to share something that heppend to me
When you create a window but forgot to put anything into a window's procedure like I did bacause I wanted to test something quickly or maybe because you handle the incoming messages incorrently? The CreateWindowEx function return NULL but when you call GetLastError it doesn't return any error and returns 0 (S_OK)
here is some simple code demonstrating the error:
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

//simple window struct
typedef struct __WINDOW {
    WNDCLASS wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    bool bRunnig;
}WINDOW;

WINDOW MainWnd = { 0 };

LRESULT WINAPI MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void DisplayError(HRESULT hrErrorCode);

int WINAPI wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInst, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInst, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd) {

    HRESULT hr = 0l;

    MainWnd.wc.hInstance = hInst;
    MainWnd.wc.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;
    MainWnd.wc.lpszClassName = L"MainCls";
    //...

    ATOM aResult = RegisterClassW(&MainWnd.wc);
    if (aResult == 0i16) {
        hr = (HRESULT)GetLastError();
        DisplayError(hr);
        ExitProcess(1u);
    }

    MainWnd.hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0l, MainWnd.wc.lpszClassName, L"Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        100, 100, 640, 480, nullptr, nullptr, hInst, nullptr);
    if (MainWnd.hwnd == nullptr) {      //CreateWindowExW returns nullptr
        hr = (HRESULT)GetLastError();   //GetLastError returns S_OK
        DisplayError(hr);
        ExitProcess(2u);
    }

    MainWnd.bRunnig = true;

    //Main Loop...
    while (MainWnd.bRunnig) {
        //...
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT WINAPI MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    //empty or not handling masseges properly?
    return 0;
}

void DisplayError(HRESULT hrErrorCode) {

    WCHAR wstrSystemError[128] = { 0 };

    FormatMessageW(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        nullptr,
        hrErrorCode,
        0l,
        wstrSystemError,
        sizeof(wstrSystemError) / sizeof(WCHAR),
        nullptr
    );

    MessageBoxW(nullptr, wstrSystemError, nullptr, MB_OK);
}


typedef struct __WINDOW -- Identifiers starting with double underscores are reserved for the compiler implementation.  Second, don't tag c if the code is C++.  There is no nullptr in C.

And since this code is clearly using C++, don't use typedef struct, just use a normal struct definition, eg: struct WINDOW { ... };

Also, there is no need to use HRESULT in this code. And, you should be using return instead of ExitProcess().

CreateWindowEx() fails if the WM_NCCREATE handler returns FALSE (as is the case in your example):

If an application processes this message, it should return TRUE to continue creation of the window. If the application returns FALSE, the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx function will return a NULL handle.

No error code is reported by GetLastError() in this situation because no system error occurred. Your own code told CreateWindowEx() to abort the creation. You might think the Win32 API would report an error like ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED or ERROR_REQUEST_ABORTED, but it doesn't.  If you want an error code in this case, you need to set it yourself, eg:
SetLastError(0);
MainWnd.hwnd = CreateWindowExW(...);
if (MainWnd.hwnd == nullptr) {
    DisplayError(GetLastError());
    return 2;
}

...

LRESULT WINAPI MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE) SetLastError(ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED);
    return 0;
}

That being said, any window message that you don't handle yourself needs to be passed to DefWindowProc() for default handling, eg:
LRESULT WINAPI MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    ...
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

